# How to splitstring values and place values into different properties

Tags: c#, string, list

I am retrieving a string value (domain list) from an HTTP service, I want the values (DomainName: Status) to bind to a repeater where I have separate labels to display the values.

```
Domain Name        Status
```

Here I separate the various domains from each other:

```
foreach(var dom in 
    _response.Split(domainList, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Now I have the string value: `domainname:status`

Here I separate these:

```
var val = dom.Split(seperation).Select(v => v.Trim()).ToList();
```

Now I have a class with 2 different properties... `Domainname` and `Status`.. 
Here I add these values to a class of this kind:

```
_searchResult.DomainName = val[0];
_searchResult.Status = val[1];
```

Here I add this class to `List<DomainClass>` : `_domainItem.Add(_searchResult);`

and then I bind this List to repeater:

```
rptDomainList.DataSource = _domainItem;
rptDomainList.DataBind();
```

The result is a list of domains, or should I say a `Domain`. I get a list of 10 domains with the same extension..

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not creating a new instance for `_searchResult` each time you are processing a new domainList item, am I right? Basically you should do `_searchResult = new ...` for each loop cycle otherwise you owerwriting previous values each new loop cycle because working with single instance (_searchResult) so final list will contains multiple searchResults with the same values (of latest domainList item)

Comment: This did the trick ;) 

 _searchResult = new DomainItem {DomainName = val[0], Status = val[1]};

1000 thanks for the help...

Comment: @Ingimar Andresson: so am I answered your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. This was my fire wuestion here .....did not find the answer button before.

Comment: @Ingimar Andresson: no problems, happy to hear that it helped you! Cheers